# How can I get a colorbar for a shapefile imported as geopandas dataframe and plotted in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

I have a shapefile that is imported as a geopandas dataframe, one of whose attributes I plot this way:

```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15, 15))
   polydat.plot(ax = ax, column = 'pptrate', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles')
   ax.set_ylim([-90, 90])
   ax.set_axis_off()
   plt.axis('equal');
```

How can I get the colorbar?

## Plot

[image]

## print(polydat.head(2))

```
   OBJECTID    POI_ID PROD_UNIT  hru_elev   hru_id2    Y_Centroid  \
0         1  23336004       17a    1829.0  17000001  2.213807e+06   
1         2  23198872       17a    1902.0  17000002  2.214667e+06   

     X_Centroid    Basin_Area  seg_hru_id    Elev_Avg  Lon_Centro  Lat_Centro  \
0 -1.665466e+06  1.202901e+08    17001133  1890.24521  -116.20479    41.33139   
1 -1.555784e+06  1.248356e+08    17000804  1959.87124  -114.91219    41.53916   

                                            geometry  pptrate  
0  POLYGON ((-1661303.114800001 2221244.977600001...      0.0  
1  (POLYGON ((-1532954.8961 2215904.7739, -153295...      0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set the `scheme='quantiles'`, you probably want to use categorical color patches for legend. You can use the `legend` option and move it outside the plot like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

ax = world.plot(column='gdp_md_est', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles', legend=True)
ax.get_legend().set_bbox_to_anchor((1.5, 1))

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you really want a colorbar, you may need to code it yourself. The following code is adapted from [`geopandas`](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/v0.3.0/geopandas/plotting.py#L455-L474):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

ax = world.plot(column='gdp_md_est', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles')

from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm
norm = Normalize(vmin=world['gdp_md_est'].min(), vmax=world['gdp_md_est'].max())
n_cmap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='OrRd')
n_cmap.set_array([])
ax.get_figure().colorbar(n_cmap)

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: geopandas can also give a colorbar, but then you cannot use `scheme='quantiles'`